# What is the best JQuery library for drawing shapes in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a drawing Web UI(Which is like MS Paint) in HTML5. I have started to work with the HTML5 canvas and with some libraries. I have tried to use http://kineticjs.com/  and http://raphaeljs.com/ to do the task. Is there a other good library like that to do the task? Or using canvas to implement this is correct?

Comment: Raphael in my experience has been pretty effective.

Comment: I use canvas. No problems so far...

Answer (score 1):

check this site, it's from John Resig.

http://processingjs.org/